# Eeek! Vote, flag, and favorite buttons are all black, and other design elements have lost their color

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Just as I was browsing the site, I saw the vote and favorite buttons lose both all their color and all their brightness:

> [image: Vote and favorite buttons lost their luminance and chrominance]

I also see that the "Similar Questions" page has lost all its color:

> [image: Monochromatic similar questions]

Additionally, the "[x] question(s) with new activity" bar has lost its background color:

> [image: "1 question with new activity" missing its background gray color]

This seems to have happened on all sites. I can reproduce this in Microsoft Edge and in Internet Explorer 11, but not in Google Chrome Canary. Regardless, can this please be fixed?

**Update:** It seems to have been fixed on Meta Stack Exchange, but it still exists on other sites in Edge, IE11, and (per Pierre.Vriens's answer) iOS Safari.

Comment: Not reproduced here; check your browser and computer.

Comment: This is happening on all sites for me, just in the last few minutes.

Comment: In addition to the vote buttons, all the flag buttons are lit.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Turns out it can't be reproduced in Chrome, only in Edge and IE11.

Comment: Not happening in responsive mobile Safari.

Comment: @Stormblessed As I said in my prior comment and the question's tags, this seems to be an Edge/IE-specific issue.

Comment: Wait a minute - it didn't reproduce, then I went to a different question, and it did reproduce. (IE11).

Comment: @AaronShekey Mind answering with details as to what caused it?

Answer (score 2):

The same horrible issue applies in iOS 9.3.5 on an iPad, where I was able to reproduce this in three different browsers, including Safari and Chrome. It reaaaaaaaaaaally looks terrible.

If this ever get fixed (rollback?), **I suggest to keep this variation to re-enable it in case something terrible happens at SE** (fingers crossed, John is still alive).

While waiting for a fix, a partial workaround, to change it to another color (blue), is to upvote/downvote/flag the posts/comments ... (not for favorites though, that remains black).

Comment: They seem to be working on it. It seems to be fixed on Meta Stack Exchange (in Edge and IE11), but it still looks wrong on other sites. Are you still seeing black here on Meta?